# Seeing Django debug 404 page despite having DEBUG = False

Tags: django, nginx

I have been following [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-20-04) along to deploy my first Django site and have successfully reached the section 'Configure Nginx to Proxy Pass to Gunicorn' which all seems to be working.

My problem is that, despite my settings.py file containing the following:

```
# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False
```

I am still getting Django's debug=true 404 page with the following error:

> "You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page."

I changed the file to DEBUG = False after completing the 'Configure Nginx to Proxy Pass to Gunicorn' step in the tutorial by pulling the change from my GitHub repository. Am I missing an additional step with Nginx in order to turn debug off and serve a standard 404 page?

Edit: It actually seems that any adjustments I make to the settings.py file in my repository, when pulled on to the server, don't have any effect. I commented out the whole settings.py file to see if it would break the webpage; nothing happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guess that you does't restart web server after code editing. Try to restart your Gunicorn server, when you work with django runserver command it automatically restart web server on any change in code. Gunicorn dont do this by default, if you wanted that Gunicorn also restart server automatically, run it with --reload argument. But it dose  not recommended into production

Comment: Yes ... many web servers effectively *cache* the running software (and related files) and so will not [necessarily ...] automatically recognize changes.  So, you simply need to *tell them* to reload.

Comment: Thank you Ivan and @mike-robinson. I ran the following commands and am now getting a "Bad Request (400)" on the same IP address.

sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart gunicorn

sudo systemctl restart nginx

Comment: Ivan, Mike, we have success! I realised that I changed ALLOWED_HOSTS to 'localhost' earlier on in an attempt to fix this. Changed it back to the IP and all is now working. Thank you both for your help, take care!